# Sacar los valores que imprime un for, PHYTON

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un programa simulador de n lanzamiento de dados, a cada lanzamiento le estoy dando un nombre, adicional necesito que me los organice de mayor a menor, es decir:

Le pedí a mi programa que hiciera 4 lanzamientos, me imprimiera los lanzamientos en forma de lista y luego le asignara un nombre a cada lanzamiento, finalmente me organizara los lanzamientos de mayor a menor, prácticamente así:

```
[16, 27, 2, 10]
Jugador 1 : 16
Jugador 2 : 27
Jugador 3 : 2
Jugador 4 : 10
De mayor a menor, los resultados fueron los siguientes: 'Jugador 2 : 27, Jugador 1 : 16, Jugador 4 : 10, Jugador 3 : 2'
```

Pero, ¡mi código no funciona!, es el siguiente:

```
import random

jugadores = int(input("Cantidad de jugadores:"))
lanzamiento_i = [random.randint(1, (30 * 1)) for _ in range(jugadores)]
print(lanzamiento_i)

#Impresión de resultados
for i in range (1, jugadores+1):
    print('Jugador', i,':', lanzamiento_i[i-1])

#Orden de juego
ordenLanzamiento = lanzamiento_i.sort()
print('De mayor a menor, los resultados fueron los siguientes:):', ordenLanzamiento)
```

Una salida de este es:

```
[16, 27, 2, 10, 1]
Jugador 1 : 16
Jugador 2 : 27
Jugador 3 : 2
Jugador 4 : 10
Jugador 5 : 1
De mayor a menor, los resultados fueron los siguientes: None
```

¿Cómo es posible hacer que se organicen de esa manera?, ¿Pueden guiarme un poco, por favor? ¡Les agradezco!

Comment: Esta es mi solución: import random

jugadores = int(input("Cantidad de jugadores:"))
lanzamiento_i = [random.randint(1, (30 * 1)) for _ in range(jugadores)]
print(lanzamiento_i)

lista_lanzamientos = []
#Impresión de resultados
for i in range (1, jugadores+1):
    print('Jugador', i,':', lanzamiento_i[i-1])
    lista_lanzamientos.append(lanzamiento_i[i-1])

#Orden de juego
ordenLanzamiento = sorted(lista_lanzamientos, reverse=True)
print('De mayor a menor, los resultados fueron los siguientes:):', ordenLanzamiento)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

El método `sort()` para listas ordena la lista donde el método ha sido llamado y como todas las funciones que hacen mutaciones (Cambios) a las listas devuelve `None`

Hay dos opciones para hacer lo que quieres

1. Utilizar directamente `lanzamiento_i` en el `print` (Ya que estás haciendo `lanzamiento_i.sort()`
2. Utilizar la función `sorted()` si deseas guardar el resultado de la lista ordenada en una nueva lista `ordenLanzamiento = sorted(lanzamiento_i)`

Te dejo los dos ejemplos funcionando

Utilizando `list.sort()`

```
import random

jugadores = int(input("Cantidad de jugadores:"))
lanzamiento_i = [random.randint(1, (30 * 1)) for _ in range(jugadores)]
print(lanzamiento_i)

#Impresión de resultados
for i in range (1, jugadores+1):
    print('Jugador', i,':', lanzamiento_i[i-1])

#Orden de juego
lanzamiento_i.sort(reverse=True)
print('De mayor a menor, los resultados fueron los siguientes:):', lanzamiento_i)
```

Utilizando `sorted()`

```
import random

jugadores = int(input("Cantidad de jugadores:"))
lanzamiento_i = [random.randint(1, (30 * 1)) for _ in range(jugadores)]
print(lanzamiento_i)

#Impresión de resultados
for i in range (1, jugadores+1):
    print('Jugador', i,':', lanzamiento_i[i-1])

#Orden de juego
ordenLanzamiento = sorted(lanzamiento_i, reverse=True)
print('De mayor a menor, los resultados fueron los siguientes:):', ordenLanzamiento)
```